# How to write bash script to open terminal tabs and run npm scripts

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, npm

I'm trying to write a bash script to do a few things at startup:

1. Open gnome terminal with 3 tabs
2. change the directory in each tab
3. run a npm script in each tab
4. leave the tabs open

I have this but it doesn't work:

```
sleep 15s; gnome-terminal --geometry=75x25 \
  --tab -e "bash -c \"cd myProjects/PWA/apps-dev;npm run dev;exec bash\"" \
  --tab -e "bash -c \"cd myProjects/PWA/walk-api;npm run dev;exec bash\"" \
  --tab -e "bash -c \"cd myProjects/PWA/sharewalks;exec bash\""
```

The tabs open, the directories get changed.

The npm scripts are ones I run manually every time I restart and they run fine.  But when I run from bash I get errors like this:

```
const path = require("path");
^^^^^
SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.
```

This seems like a versioning thing?  Can anyone help?

Comment: Btw, are you aware of `screen` and `tmux`?

Comment: no - never heard of them.  Noob here.

Comment: Have you tried using && instead of;

Comment: Feels like some environment variables are missing, or maybe some paths in PATH variable

Comment: If you're interfacing with a UI, you might like something like this:

http://www.sikuli.org